# What is an order of an element of a partition"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

I'm reading a paper, in which the set of all 3^3 mappings from {0,1,2} to itself (for instance {001,020,110,121,122}, {002,010,112,011}, {0,1,2}, ...) is partitioned, after which is written two concepts: **"order of an element of partition"**, and **"generated elements belong to partition"**, what do they mean? It isn't explained here

Comment: ..where is that and who is the author?

Comment: [here](http://www.ijirset.com/upload/october/50_Commutative.pdf)

Comment: Here's the whole sentence **Partition the set of n^n mappings in such a way that element of same partition can be obtained by using one-one 
and onto mapping from S onto S.**

Comment: You did notice that "order of an element" is defined in **II. General Concepts**, right?

Comment: I know what  an order of an element of a group is, and I know what a generator set of a group is, but here I can't understand the meaning of these concepts. The partition is doing by a defined way ( I can explain it on an example).

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Let's consider the question on an example.
If our set to be partitioned is all 2^2 mappings from {0,1} to itself :  { {00}, {01}, {10}, {11} } after partitioning (by the algorithm defined in my paper) we obtain: { {00,11}, {01}, {10} } what's the order of an element of partition and generated elements belong to partition?

Comment: Noone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The authors are partitioning the set $\mathscr{F}$ of the $27$ functions from $S=\{0,1,2\}$ to $S$. For brevity we denote by $abc$ the function $f\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $f(0)=a,f(1)=b$, and $f(2)=c$. Two functions $f,g\in\mathscr{F}$ are *equivalent* if there is a permutation $\varphi$ of $S$ such that $g=\varphi\circ f$. This really is an equivalence relation, since $g=\varphi\circ f$ if and only if $f=\varphi^{-1}\circ g$, and $\varphi^{-1}$ is also a permutation of $S$. Thus, it induces a permutation of $\mathscr{F}$ into equivalence classes.

It turns out that this partition has $7$ parts. In the numbering of Table $3$:

- Part $1$ contains the $3$ constant functions: $000$, $111$, and $222$.
- Part $2$ contains the $6$ functions that have exactly one fixed point and send exactly one other point to that fixed point: $001$, $020$, $110$, $211$, $202$, and $122$.
- Part $3$ contains the $6$ functions that have exactly $2$ fixed points: $002$, $022$, $010$, $011$, $112$, and $212$.
- Part $4$ contains the only function with $3$ fixed points, the identity function $012$.
- Part $5$ contains the $3$ bijections with exactly one fixed point: $021$, $210$, and $102$.
- Part $6$ contains the $6$ functions with no fixed points and a $2$-element range: $100$, $200$, $101$, $121$, $220$, and $221$.
- Part $7$ contains the $2$ derangements, the bijections with no fixed points: $120$ and $201$.

Note that these are renumbered in Table $4$. To see where the rest of Table $4$ comes from, start with the function $120$, representing what is now being called the first part of the partition. Remember that this is really the function $f$ such that $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=2$, and $f(2)=0$. Thus, $f^2=f\circ f$ satisfies $f^2(0)=2$, $f^2(1)=0$, and $f^2(2)=1$, so $f^2$ is the function $201$, which is also in this part of the partition. The function $f^3=f\circ f\circ f$, however, is $012$, which is in what is now numbered part $7$ of the partition. Since $f^3$ is the identity function, higher powers of $f$ will just be $f,f^2$, or $f^3$, so the set of functions generated by $f$ (by composing it repeatedly with itself) is $\{120,201,012\}$, and $f$ is of order $3$. The point of the earlier discussion in the paper is that every function equivalent to $f$ will behave similarly, generating two functions (including itself) in this part of the partition, and the identity function.

Just to be sure, let’s look at one other example: take $f$ to be $100$. Then $f^2$ is $011$, and $f^3=f$, so every power of $f$ is either $100$, in what is now part $3$, or $011$, in what is now part $5$ (i.e., equivalent to $002$).

This fully explains Table $4$ and the terminology about which you asked.

Comment: Thank you so much, you explained what I couldn't understand during one week. Now I'll try to understand the third step, I think already I can understand the third step too.

Comment: @David: You’re very welcome. It took me a while to realize what they were doing in the second step; that paper is very badly written.

Comment: It is right. It's very hard to read the paper(exactly for me), but it's important for me to understand what is written ( I must do it today). Please explain the third step. ( what does this mean? **when one row is fill by the first element of i-th partition which can also fill k-1 more rows and remaining row n-k can be filled by i-th and onwards partitions (if any)** ).

Comment: @BrianScott could you help me?

Comment: @David: I was offline most of the day, so I’ve only just seen this. So far I don’t see just what they’re doing in this step. I’ll play with it a bit more, but I’m not very hopeful of working it out quickly.

Comment: @BrianScott Okay dear professor. Please when you are free  take a look the paper, I'll be very pleased.